# Why is $wp_query fetching nothing?

Tags: wp-query, ajax

I have created a ajax file from where response will return named "ajax_show_nxt_cat.php" and here I want to list all post using $wp_query but when I try to print the $wp_query, it returns nothing.
I am using following code.

```
<?php $vidId = $_REQUEST['id']; ?>
<?php
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
?>  
    <?php $term =   $wp_query->queried_object; ?>
    <?php $current_slug= $term->slug; ?>
    <?php 

      $paged = $vidId;
        $all_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'videos',
    'post_parent' => 0,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'tax_query' => array(

    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'video-category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array($current_slug),

    ),
    ),
    );
     ?>


    <?php $all_vid = new WP_Query( $all_args );
        echo "count is".$total_post_cnt=$all_vid->post_count;
    $i=1;
    if( $all_vid->have_posts() ) : while( $all_vid->have_posts() ) : $all_vid->the_post();
    ?>
        <?php if($i==1){ ?></ul><ul><?php }?>
    <li <?php if($i%4==0){ ?>class="fourth-one"<?php }?>>
      <div class="video-thumb">
       <a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/video-list/?show-id=<?php echo get_the_ID();  //the_permalink(); ?>">
       <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail();
        }
        else {
            echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/no-thumbnail.png" />';
        }
       ?>
       </a>
      </div>
      <div class="video-title"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/video-list/?show-id=<?php echo get_the_ID();  //the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></div>
      <div class="video-desc"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/video-list/?show-id=<?php echo get_the_ID();  //the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php $detailarr=get_post(get_the_ID(), ARRAY_A); echo $detailarr['post_excerpt'];?></a></div>
      <div class="video-links"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/video/">Video</a> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/video-category/<?php echo $current_slug;?>/"><?php echo $current_cat_name;?></a></div>
    </li>
    <?php if($i%4==0 and $i < $total_post_cnt){ ?></ul><ul><?php }?>
    <?php
    $i=$i+1;
    endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php if($total_post_cnt == ($i -1) ){ echo '</ul>';} ?>
    <?php 
    if($all_vid->found_posts < 1){
    ?>
    <div class="no-data"><strong>No video yet.</strong></div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

but as said above $wp_query prints nothing when I do like this

```
 <?php print_r($wp_query); ?>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you don't show us more code, all we can is `$wp_query` is an undefined variable. Do you have more code to show?

Comment: see my updated question

Comment: Your query here seems to be named `$all_vid`, not `$wp_query`. And the place where you're referencing `$wp_query->queried_object` will be blank because you're not running WordPress in the normal manner, so there is no queried_object for it to get. Essentially, this code is wrong in multiple ways and it's difficult to understand exactly what it is that you're attempting to do.

Comment: I confirm it, `$wp_query` is an undefined variable in your code. You expect `$wp_query` be someting, but the variable is not initialized anywhere before. Then, you make a custom query named `$all_vid`, name you have to use if you want to access to data from that custom query.

Comment: you're doing it wrong.. `$wp_query` is undefined in here... I'm not even sure if `global $wp_query;` can help... I have never tried, but I think `$wp_query` is only visible inside the loop or somewhere with `global $wp_query;`

Comment: I'm thinking that you might just have to pass the slug as parameter... then do something like `$_REQUEST['slug']`

Comment: You all are not giving me the right answer, why $wp_query prints nothing when I print it like print_r($wp_query)

Comment: the answer is you're doing it wrong.. lol...